# Converting an Arrow Style function to "function" style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, arrow-functions

I have a function like this:

```
const jsonObject = {a: {b: 'c'}};
const x = 'a.b';
const properties = x.split('.');

const item = properties.reduce((obj, prop) => obj && obj[prop], jsonObject);

console.log(item); // prints 'c;
```

This function, dynamically traverses the jsonObject and prints the value.

This works fine, but this style of declaration doesn't support my environment. So I wan trying to convert this to function style declaration something like this:

```
const item = properties.reduce(function(obj, prop){
   if(obj && obj[prop]) return obj[prop];
});
```

But this doesn't seems to be working. Its printing (item) undefined.

Comment: Simply return the expression, you don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you everyone.. i randomly choose one answer and upvoted all correct answers. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Working Snippet

```js
const jsonObject = {
  a: {
    b: 'c'
  }
};
const x = 'a.b';
const properties = x.split('.');

const item = properties.reduce(function(obj, prop) {
  return obj && obj[prop];
}, jsonObject);

console.log(item); // prints 'c;
```

> Explanation

1. Fat arrow (=>) returns anything written on the right side by default (i.e. without a block as a body)
2. While porting to a function expression or declaration, we need to explicitly use the `return` keyword.

Comment: *"Fat arrow (=>) returns anything written on the right side by default"* That's not quite correct. If the arrow function has a "block body" then it only returns something if the the body contains a `return` statement. *"While porting to anonymous function..."* It's irrelevant whether the function is anonymous or not.

Comment: @FelixKling I am aware of that, that's why I said by default and the default fat arrow expression is without a block body.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, It is actually irrelevant whether the function is anonymous or not

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the term "default" in this context. You have the choice between using an expression or a block, similar to how it works for `if` statements. But there is no "default" behavior, you have to choose one or the other, you cannot simply *not choose* either. Maybe you mean that the "most common" use case is to use an expression. Anyways, being explicit (as you are now) is always better. Not everybody will understand your definition of "default behavior".

Comment: @FelixKling Your reasoning makes sense, thank you for your insight. I'll keep those pointers in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
const item = properties.reduce((obj, prop) => obj && obj[prop], jsonObject);
```

Is similar to

```
const item = properties.reduce(function(obj, prop){
   return obj && obj[prop];
}, jsonObject);
```

Read more about .reduce and its arguments [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct translation would be:

```
function(obj, prop) {
    return obj && obj[prop];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
const item = properties.reduce(function(obj, prop){
  if(obj && obj[prop]) return obj[prop];
});
```

You are never passing the jsonObject in as the second parameter to the function, so `.reduce` doesn't know what to enumerate on. The correct way of doing it is:

```
const item = properties.reduce(function(obj, prop){
  if(obj && obj[prop]) return obj[prop];
}, jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

An awesome online tool [BabelJs](https://babeljs.io/)

It can help you with converting your ES6 to ES5 without much effort. However I recommend understanding how its doing the conversion

```
   'use strict';

    var jsonObject = { a: { b: 'c' } };
    var x = 'a.b';
    var properties = x.split('.');

    var item = properties.reduce(function (obj, prop) {
      return obj && obj[prop];
    }, jsonObject);

    console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add a default value for preventing a not given property in the object.

```
const item = properties.reduce(function (obj, prop){
        return (obj || {})[prop];
    }, jsonObject);
```