# Ninja Forms have arrow function which is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm using Ninja Forms for my Wordpress project. It is not working in IE. After checking console I found out that the scripts for Ninja Forms contains arrow functions and hence it is not working in IE.

I tried to convert from ES6 to ES5 but additional errors pops up. Is there any way where I can use a Ninja Forms version with no arrow functions

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074757/converting-an-arrow-style-function-to-function-style

Comment: "It is not working in IE." — [not even microsoft supports IE any more](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2022/06/15/internet-explorer-11-has-retired-and-is-officially-out-of-support-what-you-need-to-know/). It should be considered a security hazard. Not a browser you need to support.

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox thanks for the reply, but i even though i know how to convert arrow functions to normal functions, it will be difficult for me to change multiple files of a plugin. so mostly I'm looking for a version which has no arrow functions, or a method to convert it to normal functions

Comment: Hey @AmalJayan, since arrow function is a syntax that was introduced in ES6, there isn't really a polyfill for it. the best you can do is manually convert them into functions, or create a script that does it for you. But then again, as Quentin mentioned, Internet Explorer has lost support for a while now and many developers has not bothered supporting it either.